# targetSdkVersion not similar in android manifest as selected while project creation

Tags: android

**I am creating a project in android using eclipse.**

Now my problem is when i create a android application project, I set `Build Sdk version to 4.1 (API 16)`. But when i saw in `manifest` file the `android:targetSdkVersion="15"` . Can anyone explain me why this is happening ? see the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible defect on the Android SDK Tools revision **20.0.3**

Comment: You may not have enough support for Android4.1 (16), so your previous version as target

Comment: @rajeshmcashc10 I tested it my self and I already have all the SDKs installed and it's gets me the same result above.

Comment: Open SDK tool Manager and update API 16 completely again

Comment: ok let me update and tell you

Comment: @ADR I updated all API 16 , but still the same problem, though the application works fine in `4.1 emulator` , but i don't understand why its showing me `android:targetSdkVersion="15"`

Comment: You change it in manifest to 16

Comment: yes i can change this to 16 but , I want to know why this is happening ? that is my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Here it goes,

Solution is,

*goto:*

> Your
>   Directory\android-sdk-windows\tools\templates\projects\NewAndroidApplication\root

*Open :*

> AndroidManifest.xml.ftl File

*Change :*

*default :*

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="${minApi}"
 android:targetSdkVersion="${targetApi}" />
```

*Modified :*

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="${minApi}"
 android:targetSdkVersion="${buildApi}" />
```

So the Problem goes here:

In the ftl file the attribute name `${targetApi}` has been set, but we are selecting the `buildApi` value in the project creation window.

`${targetApi}` or `${buildApi}` default value is the higher version , that means in your SDK tool it is API 15. So it is always 15 in the Manifest.

If you tried to create a new project with target API less than 10 or more than 15 anything , in the manifest it will be denoted as 15 only always.

Try this:

Create a project with API target 8 and see , manifest target will be 15 only. (Before modify the ftl file).
But `project.properties` has been updated properly.

So if you change `${targetApi}` to `${buildApi}` in the `Manifest.xml.ftl`, the problem solved.

It is a possible error in SDK tools revision 20, Even i updated the SDK tools itsn't resolved in the recent revision also.

Hope this one might be helpful for somebody, those who facing the same.

**Older Answer:**

It is showing for me too. But in my case, I selected API 14 and it is showing `android:targetSdkVersion="15"` in the manifest.

I guess some reason should be there... 4.0 or 4.2 , it is assigning 4.1 in the manifest... Or may be a bug with Eclipse IDE. Why cant you update the newer version of Eclipse IDE and try it out. This might be a IDE Problem only.

Can you see that Right click- Properties - Android , Checked one is same what you selected in the beginning.

And also project.properties has the same version what you selected in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

well the  Project target you set is got set in the default.properties file if you change that and save it the the attached sdk will change you can try it.

the entry in menifiest is used after compilation on the device . don't know why it is taking wrong value.but in my eclipse it takes only minsdkversion and its value is same what i entered on start.**however my point is it does not matter**